# Como criar pergunta "deseja continuar?" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, funções, algoritmo

Realizei um projeto simples que a partir de uma nota específica, um aluno é aprovado, retido ou fica em recuperação.

Este código está escrito em uma função, que, eu gostaria de retornar toda vez que o usuário precisasse escrever o nome de um novo aluno e sua nota (para saber se o mesmo foi validado ou não).

Porém, o algoritmo entra em um "loop" infinito onde se trava na pergunta "Deseja continuar?" (mesmo eu usando condicionais `if` e `else`, ou até "loops" como `while`).

O código-fonte é este:

```
//Definição de professores e alunos.
var nome_Professor 
var nome_Aluno
var nota_Aluno
 var confirmar

//Introdução ao usuário
console.log("Bem-vindo ao nosso programa de validação de alunos!")
console.log("Digite seu nome, logo após nome de aluno e então a nota do aluno, e, lhe traremos a validação, ou não, do aluno!")

//Identificação de professor
nome_Professor = prompt("Digite seu nome: ")
console.log("Bem-vindo(a) " + nome_Professor + "!")
if (nome_Professor = nome_Professor)

//Teste de validação
{
function teste_Aluno()
  {
    nome_Aluno = prompt("Digite nome do aluno: ")
    nota_Aluno = prompt("Digite a nota do aluno " +     
    nome_Aluno + ": ")
    if (nota_Aluno >= 7)
    {
      console.log("Aluno aprovado!")
    }
    if (nota_Aluno >= 5)
    {
      if (nota_Aluno <= 6)
      {
        console.log("Aluno em recuperação!")
        retorno_Funcao()
      }
      retorno_Funcao()
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("Aluno reprovado!")
      retorno_Funcao()
    }
  }
}

//Opção de novos alunos
function retorno_Funcao()
{
 confirmar = prompt("Deseja continuar?[S/N]: ")
 if (confirmar = "S")
   {
     teste_Aluno()
   }
  else
 {
 console.log("Obrigado!")
}
}
//Finalização
function finalizar()
  {
    console.log("Volte sempre!")
  }
//Execução de opção de novos alunos e teste de validação
teste_Aluno()
finalizar()
```

Comment: Se vocês me ajudarem com isso eu ficaria muito agradecido.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, seu problema é que a função `teste_Aluno` sempre está sendo chamada depois do `prompt` com a pergunta "Deseja continuar?", independentemente da resposta do usuário.

O problema está na condição abaixo:

```
if (confirmar = "S") {
    teste_Aluno()
} else {
    console.log("Obrigado!")
}
```

Você não está verificando se o valor de confirmar é "S", visto que `=` é um operador de atribuição, utilizado para atribuir um valor a determinada variável, como sabe. Para realizar a verificação, deve-se usar um operador de igualdade, de preferência, o de igualdade estrita (`===`). Seu código seria praticamente o mesmo:

```
if (confirmar === "S") {
    teste_Aluno()
} else {
    console.log("Obrigado!")
}
```